# Cron Job PHP File

Tags: php, cron

I want to make a PHP script to be ran once daily. Once run, it will write certain information inside a .txt file. As I understood that newline for Windows("\r\n") and Mac("\n"), is different. Which syntax will the Cron Job follows for a newline ?

Is it okay if I just use `PHP_EOL` command ?

Comment: If it's running on Linux, it's \n

Comment: The cronjob does only schedule the exeuction.

Comment: The cron doesn't care, it's job is to run a specified command at the scheduled time

Comment: What's a line break have to do with a cron job?